# Creating a Raw Data File in SAS

Tags: sas

This is such a beginners' question, but I would like to know how to create a raw data file.

I am thinking that a SAS data set and a raw data file are not the same thing.

So, I think that an example of a way to making a raw data file is to simply type numbers and characters in a notepad.

But is there a way to create a raw data file in SAS?

I especially would like to have the

--------10--------20----------30

this thing that helps identify the column of the observations.

I truly apologize for my lack of appropriate vocabularies, and thank you for your help.

Comment: Example 2 in the docs https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=n1xrpfyevzkdaen1m1meb5z8qwc6.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: How are you interacting with SAS?  Are you using SAS/Studio? Enterprise Guide?  SAS Display Manager?

Answer (score 1):

The original SAS program editor in Display Manger is a good way to do this.  If you are running on Windows then you can use the `pgm` command to open it. If you are using Display Manager in Unix it is the only editor window.  Type COLS in the line number area. (If you don't see the line numbers use the NUMS command).

[image]